# Showing users in tree structure?

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

I have a database table called `users`

This table has two columns (that are important)

`uuid`, and `parentUuid`

Here are the rules for the table:

- If a user invites another user, the invited users `parentUuid` column is equal to the `uuid` of the inviter.
- If a user was not invited, their `parentUuid` column is `null`
- There can be infinite levels of users.

What I want to do is, create a function  `function counter($levels, $uuid){}`

When counter is called (lets assume $levels = 3)

I want the function to return an array that 
looks like

`array(0 => 200, 1 => 600, 2 => 1800);`

So the basic idea is I want it to count down, for `$levels` levels how many users are in the tree under the user.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What does happen if user A invited user B and user B invited user A?

Comment: well, What I am currently doing is, `select * from users where parentUuid = '[users uuid]';` then count all users, then put all uuid's into a comma seperated string, the do the same, for each level, by use where `parentUuid in ([comma seperated string])` But it is highly inefficient.

Comment: @hakre, Cannot happen, a user must be joined to invite another user, hence to join they must have either: used a invite link, or a raw join.

Comment: Take a look http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html . You will find very useful solutions for traversing your table.

Comment: @Hailwood - and who tells you that not something like that slipped into your data by error? Your db design does not prevent this, right?

Comment: @hakre, the only way something like that could happen is if someone went in and manually modified the database, and why on earth would anyone do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is hierarchical data stored in a tree using the adjacency list model. This is very difficult to scale. Try converting it into a nested set instead. What the difference is and how to structure your data is very well explained here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 3):

I'd extend your users table to include a "level" column, that indicates the depth in level from the root that the user is.  That way, when a new user gets added, their level just gets set to the parent's level + 1.

I know this is a bit different of a solution than what you're asking for, but the traversal process for getting the data you want from a table that doesn't store user levels is tricky at best, and the execution time is potentially very long.  This seems to be a good example of a situation where the best solution is a slight modification to your schema.

Comment: This is a possible solution, however after adding the level column, what would my query look like (lets assume our inital users id is 381)

Comment: Also, this becomes difficult, because, as far as each user is concerned, they are the top of their own pyramid, hence, user a is 0 to everyone (no parent) user b is o to themself, but 1 to user a, user c is 0 to themself, but 1 to iser b, and 2 to user c... so what on earth would I store in the level column?

Comment: @hailwood: you would do an (INSERT INTO [yourtable]  (userid, parentid, level) VALUES ({newuserid}, {parentid}, (SELECT LEVEL FROM [yourtable] WHERE userid={parentid})))

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of storing hierarchical data in a database. I suggest using Materialized Path. Failing that, Nested Sets and Adjacency Lists also work.

https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-9902

Comment: Lame...sorry about that. I just linked to one of the main docs on materialized path.

Answer (score 0):

SAP uses hierarchies almost everywhere this the the structure of the table:

Firstly you need to make sure that your list of entries has a unique identifier UnID even if the bit of information you need is not the UnID. The UnID can be numeric for ease of incrementation.

Then when you add items to your hierarchy table you should store them in this format:

```
NodeID  
    Note: 0 is always the root nodeID. Any other entry is the UnId of the new entry. It can never be null

ParentID 
    Note: this is the UnID of the parent that you want to attribute to the new entry. It can never be null

ChildId 
    Note: this can be null. It is updated only when this New entry gets to be a parent. 

NextId 
    Note: this is the important one. It determines which child is next in the sequence of children below the parent. The last one in the sequence is always null

Level
    Note: this ensures that a UnID cannot be the parent at more than one level.
```

You will need some program logic to iron out the attempts to create circular references mentioned in a comment somewhere here, but by implication this means that when a referral takes place you must update three records in your hierarchy table: The new entry, the parent and the last child of the parent (with the nextID) to ensure your pyramid is correct.